# Загрузка бота на https://www.pythonanywhere.com

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram, pythonanywhere

В pycharm работает, запускаю на [www.pythonanywhere.com](http://www.pythonanywhere.com), выдает ошибку.
В чем проблема?

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 986, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1056, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1041, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 955, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 502, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 507, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1138, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 535, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 542, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 907, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1206, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1175, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 992, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/main.py", line 215, in <module>
    executor.start_polling(dp,on_startup=on_startup)
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 45, in start_polling
    executor.start_polling(
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 320, in start_polling
    loop.run_until_complete(self._startup_polling())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 372, in _startup_polling
    await self._welcome()
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 361, in _welcome
    user = await self.dispatcher.bot.me
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 30, in me
    setattr(self, '_me', await self.get_me())
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 233, in get_me
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_ME, payload)
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 231, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "/home/pgrevyazko/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 142, in make_request
    raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network 
is unreachable]```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте прокси сервер

```py
import subprocess
from aiogram import Bot
from aiogram.client.session.aiohttp import AiohttpSession

proxy = subprocess.getoutput("echo $http_proxy") # Обычно http://proxy.server:3128

session = AiohttpSession(proxy=proxy)
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, session=session)
```

Answer (score 1):

у вас бесплатный аккаунт? если да то проблема в том что вам сервер дал слишком мало интернета, и тг этого недостаточно для работы с ботом

пропробуйте хероку, но предупреждаю - там 28 ноября уберут возможность получать бесплатные 500 часов каждый месяц (короче он станет платным, но пока что есть фора)

Answer (score 0):

pythonanywhere даёт специальные прокси для программ, запущенных у них.

Заметьте, что если вы попытаетесь послать запрос на `api.telegram.org:443` через командную строку: `curl -k https://api.telegram.org:443` (-k для https запроса), то всё будет нормально, т.е. апи телеграма достижимо.

Как уже говорил [@Максим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/553226/maxim), обычно url адрес прокси - `http://proxy.server:3128`, но не всегда. Чтобы узнать адрес прокси для вас, необходимо выполнить команду `echo $http_proxy`.

Подробнее можно узнать [здесь](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError#proxy-details).