# aiogram не работает на pythonanywhere

Tags: python, aiogram

Всем доброго дня. Проблема в том что телеграмм бот на пайтоне с использованием aiogram не работает на pythonanywhere. Но на моем компе всё отлично. Я заметил что сам скрипт пайтон на pythonanywhere работает например с модулем requests и тд. И даже такой же бот сделал на telebot, и даже он сработал на pythonanywhere. Вопрос такой с чем это связано. Может быть из за того что я использую бесплатную версию pythonanywhere? Просто я хотел купить уже нормальный платный тарифный план и будет ли мой бот на aiogram работать на pythonanywhere?

Comment: [Тут почитайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1438874/479903)